# sizeof(void) == 1?

Tags: c, sizeof

Случайно опечатался и получил от оператора sizeof - 1.

```
#include "stdio.h"
int main(void) 
{
    printf("%d",sizeof(void)); /// 1
    return 0;
}
```

Может мне кто-нибудь объяснить в чем тут дело?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666224/what-is-the-size-of-void вопрос на SO. Говорят что в gcc какой-то костыль, если с ключами собирать вообще не собёртся

Comment: Это сообщение об ошибке :) Кстати, в Visual C++ в режиме C выдается предупреждение (и значение 0), а в режиме C++ - ошибка.

Comment: Если коротко и чисто практически, то (по крайней мере в gcc) адресная арифметика для `void *` та же, что и для `char *`. Поэтому, т.к. `sizeof(char) == 1`, то и `sizeof(void) == sizeof(char) == 1`. ( g++ для `sizeof(void)` пишет warning, но компилирует и результат будет тот же -- 1)

Comment: @avp забавная вещь

Comment: Ну, понятно же, что void это что-то. Да, мы не знаем что именно, но не пустое же место (как представить пустое место в памяти? (чисто аппаратно)), вот и решим, что его размер 1 (по крайней мере уж 1-то адрес эта штука должна занимать). Вот, примерно такие рассуждения.

Comment: @avp это сильная абстракция, можно как-то более наглядней?

Comment: Не знаю. Я думал это тривиально. Представьте память. К ней мы обращаемся по адресам. Если последовательно их перебирать и выбирать минимум данных, то будем получать объекты типа `char` (та же логика и для `void`, за тем исключением, что с ним мы ничего кроме как адресовать делать не можем, даже копировать из/в него)

Comment: @avp я видимо спать хочу, не сразу осмыслил, но я уже все понял

Comment: @avp вы видимо сейчас говорите о `char *` и `void *`? копировать из/в `void *` можно, только разименовывать нельзя, а так можно делать арифметические операции над адресом.

Comment: @avp адрес `void` можно узнать =)?

Comment: Если имеете в виду объекта типа `void`? то нет, конечно. Такой объект виртуален. Его нельзя создать, т.к. `void *` нельзя разыменовать. Да не ищите вы тут глубокой философской системы, все ради практического удобства. Понадобился просто адрес (указатель) на что угодно. Этот тип назвали `void *` и решили что будет удобно, если он сможет иметь любое значение (вот и получился в смысле адресной арифметики аналог `char *`)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Согласно стандарту C (раздел 6.2.5 Types)

> 19 **The void type** comprises an empty set of values; it **is an
>   incomplete object type** that cannot be completed.

и  (6.5.3.4 The sizeof and alignof operators)

> 1 The sizeof operator **shall not be applied to** an expression that
>   has function type or **an incomplete type**, to the parenthesized name
>   of such a type, or to an expression that designates a bit-ﬁeld member.
>   The alignof operator shall not be applied to a function type or an
>   incomplete type.

Однако некоторые компиляторы имеют собственные расширения языка, которые все же определяют выражение `sizeof( void )`, как имеющее значение 1.

Дело в том, что тип `void` не сразу же появился в языке программирования C.  Из Rationale for International Standard— Programming Languages— C раздел 6.4.1    Keywords

> **Several keywords were added in C89**:  const, enum, signed, **void** and 
>   volatile.

Ранее его роль играл тип `char`. Например, если вы хотели скопировать один объект в другой с использованием  стандартной функции `memmove`, то соответствующая запись могла выглядеть как

```
memmove( ( char *)obj1, ( char * )obj2, n );
```

Подобного вида запись еще можно встретить в старых программах.

В настоящее время функция `memmove` имеет следующее объявление

```
void *memmove(void *s1, const void *s2, size_t n);
```

и, как известно, любой указатель может быть приведен неявно к типу `void *`, а потому никакого явного приведения типов для вызова этой функции не требуется. Вы можете написать просто

```
memmove( obj1, obj2, n );
```

при использовании этой функции с указателями любого типа.

И лишь со временем я C был введен тип `void`.

Из Rationale for International Standard— Programming Languages— C раздел 6.5.4    Cast operators

> The **new** type void*, which has the same representation as char*,
>   is therefore preferable for arbitrary pointers

По аналогии с типом `char`, так как указатели `void *` имеют такое же представление, как и указатели `char *`, в некоторых компиляторах сделали  размер `void` равным 1, так как `sizeof( *(char *)NULL )` равно 1. Однако, как следует из стандарта C этот тип не имеет размера, так как он всегда является неполным типом, а потому такая конструкция, как `sizeof( void )`, является некорректной, и компилтор должен выдавать сообщения об ошибке, если его собственные расширения отключены при компиляции программы.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51720/discussion-on-answer-by-vlad-from-moscow-sizeofvoid-1).

Comment: @Nofate Да, что уж там! Удаляйте сам ответ, так как он вызывает холивар1

Comment: Комментарии не удалены, а перенесены в чат.

Answer (score -1):

```
printf("%lu",sizeof(void));
```

Так точнее. Это размер типа void.

Comment: кхм... вопрос не в этом. Вас не смущает что там не  0 например?

Comment: меня нет, а вас чем смущает? Тип данных как информация должен иметь какой-то размер.

Comment: @pavel с нулем не получалось бы разницу между двумя void* получить

Comment: @VladimirGamalian а при чем тут `void *`?

Comment: @dio4 и какую _информацию_ хранит этот тип?)

Comment: @pavelинформацию о типе void

Comment: @dio4 Примеры информации которую может хранить тип `void` можете привести?

Comment: @MaximPro вы меня тестируете? Или у вас вопрос? Можно в чате продолжить, чтобы не засорять тему лично моей персоной. Ног раз спросили отвечу - например, приведение указателя к типу void для того, чтобы в итоге он мог указывать на любой тип данных. Широко применяется при использовании функции  sort()

Comment: @dio4 то что вы сказали не является `void`, а является `void *`. И да это не тестирование, просто реально интересно, вдруг я чего-то не знал =)

Comment: @MaximPro void *  есть указатель на данные типа void - согласны? Я про эти данные и говорю. Я думаю - вы все это знаете ;)   может заскучали просто... )  возможно еще функция типа void тоже может быть примером. а что - реальный тип возвращаемого значения )) можно даже return не писать ))

Comment: @dio4 неа, несогласен! Докажите что `void * есть указатель на данные типа void`. Как такового типа void нет! Есть только указатель типа void. И есть спецификатор void. А как самостоятельный тип void - нет. Ну по-крайней мере я ничего не слышал.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51318/discussion-between-dio4-and-maximpro).

Comment: Информация о значении типа `void` прекрасно помещается в 0 бит, т. к. возможное значение для этого типа всего одно. Отсюда и другие ограничения, вроде запрета на создание переменных типа `void`, это просто бессмысленно. Поэтому и правда интересно, с какого перепугу там не 0. Да, принятый ответ объясняет, как так получилось, но получается, что это прямо в стандарте несогласованность, лишнее "исключение". Другой вопрос -- кому она мешает и есть ли смысл это исправлять. Вроде бы все привыкли. А спорить о дизайне Си как языка смысла мало :)